# Green long caterpiller like bugs [pics included] on my Cassia fistula

Tags: flowers, bugs

This [fowering plant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassia_fistula) is in its early developing stage, but these tiny soldiers are carving it upside down(the leaves). Take a look:
[image: bug]

```
Another lovely plant, that is fully grown, just next to it.
```

[image: Another fully grown plant in the backyard]

```
This is the smallest of all, now they've grown in to pinky-sized pirates! 
What can I do? Any home-made remedies (there are huge amounts of these, 2 per leaf)
```

Comment: caterpillars are soft bodied insects and are vulnerable to soap and water. But...the problem is getting coverage. You need a sprayer that can provide good pressure to cover the leaves.

Answer (score 1):

Try BT: Bacillus thuringiensis for caterpillars.  This bacteria produces a toxin when eaten by caterpillars makes them think they are full, they stop eating and starve to death.  Very specific pesticide. Rent a good sprayer from a tool rental place that can shoot up to the top of your trees.  Spray when there is no wind, read the directions 5X (honest, this is what we are taught in pesticide applicator licensing classes)...pretty safe pesticide.